# How do i get my 'See more' ("seemorelink") link to position closer to my image?

Tags: html, css

I want my 'See more' link to move closer to my image. I have tried to change the margin for the images and the 'See more' links but it still stays in the same position.

Here below is one of the images and the 'See more' links that i am talking about.

[image]

Here below are screenshots of my css and html file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the HTML with your CSS

Comment: I just included screenshots of my html and css file.

Comment: You need to include the HTML of the .seemorelink span and possibly more CSS for this to make sense. Did you try to inspect the element in your browser?

Comment: you need to provide actual source code. People won't likely retype your code to check in their own environment.

Answer (score 1):

I need to see more of your code to reproduce the issue.
You already checked the margin, but can you also check if it's not caused by padding?
Try set both to 0

```
padding: 0;
```

Comment: I just included screenshots of my html and css file.